# ASP.net centering calendar control

Tags: css, asp.net

Simple question but gives me problem: How to center the position of a calendar?

I've tried:

```
   <asp:Calendar  ID="Calendar1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center"...
```

or after putting it into a table:

```
   <td style="text-align":center">
```

or

```
   <td align="center">
```

(latest one is apparently invalid in HTML5)

Edit: This seems to be working, but I'd prefer not to use fixed width...

```
 <div id="cal1Container" class="calendar" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 200px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you can do fixed width, you could try this within the container you want the calendar to reside.

```
<div style="width:200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"><asp:Calendar ... /></div>
```

Comment: yes, I've tried that, but I'd prefer to avoid using fixed width

Answer (score 0):

In your css try:

```
td { text-align: center; }
td * { display: inline; }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can't do that since it will messed up other <td>

Comment: Then add a class to the td where you want to see those attributes.

<td class="myClass"> </td>

td.myClass { text-align: center; }
td.myClass * { display: inline; }

Comment: unfortunately that compresses calendar to a single line

Answer (score 0):

Place your calendar within a set of 
    `<div>` `</div>`

tags, use the following code in CSS:

```
#myCalendarName{
    display: block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: mywidthhere;
    height: myheighthere;
}
```

That should do it.